# Is there a surge suppressor or power strip that doesn't draw power when switched off?

Tags: device, outlet

I've read that leaving electronics plugged in but not being used still draws power. Is this true? But if it was turned off it would probably not draw as much power as it would be if it was turned on? The resistor is simply resisting the current?

And what about surge suppressors or power strips? If an electronic device is plugged into a surge suppressor and the surge suppressor is turned off is that equivalent to having the device completely unplugged? Or is there one that uses the most minimal amount of power in off mode? I've added a photo below of a specific power strip but it can be any brand.

As an example, take a CD player. In multiple cases:

- it is plugged into the wall and turned on
- it is plugged into the wall and turned on and in use at a loud volume
- it is plugged into the wall and turned off
- it is plugged into a surge suppressor and the surge suppressor is turned off

More background:
I'm trying to see if it is better to keep an appliance unplugged and only plug it in when it is needed or if I can plug the appliance into a surge suppressor and use the switch to provide power when needed. I would rather use a surge suppressor so it doesn't harm the cord or the outlet by being unplugged and plugged in again.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a surge protective device (SPD) of some specific sort, or just a power strip which claims to do such?

Comment: @TimWilliams Something you'd buy at the store for $10 - $20. A power strip and or a surge suppressor

Comment: `But if it was turned off` ... anything that responds to a remote control is not turned off completely

Comment: Can't really answer this question until you start talking schematics. It really depends on where the switch is and if it has a filter on the line.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I haven't purchased a power strip yet so I am open to purchasing one that would address this. Are there power strips that are aware of what I'm talking about and do what I want?

Comment: Those are not surge suppressors. They are simply power strips with a mains switch. If it does surge suppression then that's an extra feature of a switchable power strip.

Comment: @Justme that's fine by me. I just want to know if the power strip (or surge suppressor) will be a better alternative to pulling the plug out of the wall (causing outlet damage).

Comment: definitely yes ...

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Either the plug and socket wears out, or the switch. You must yourself decide which is better.

Comment: "I have read" doesn't mean a _thing_ without a reference to the source, or at least a quote of the statement and the surrounding text.  _Some_ modern consumer electronic devices (possibly most) don't turn all the way off when you switch off the power button.  Some do.  But _we can't tell_ if that's what the original author meant without a citation.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, the power buttons on most electronic devices worked by interrupting power to the device. It was simply a mechanical switch in line with the AC supply or batteries in portable equipment.

Now it's common to use electronic switching. Instead of an ON/OFF switch that has to handle whatever current the device needs, they use a low current push-button and that controls circuitry that powers up or down the device. This also allows the possibility of remote control switching and things like sleep timers as well as real time clocks that still need power when the main device is off.

In order for the electronic switching to work, it needs to be supplied with a small amount of power all the time. So when you turn a device off, it's more like a sleep mode, most of the circuitry is powered off but some power is still drawn to keep the switching circuity ready to respond to a button press or remote control.

The amount of power used by this is small, you're not going to save the planet or tons of money on your electric bill by unplugging your CD player when not using it.

A switched outlet strip will almost undoubtedly just have a mechanical switch that cuts the power off completely, so yes, in general you can use one instead of unplugging your devices.

Answer (score 1):

Many electronic devices use power at all times.  A cell phone charging block, for instance, must make power all the time because it never knows when a phone will be plugged in. That is especially true for devices with "soft" controls - where it's a tiny passive switch, or remote, or triggered by some activity.  Because part of the system must be powered up to listen for the "turn on" signal.  This is called vampire load.

But don't guess - find out by getting a Kill-A-Watt energy monitor and measuring the device's load over a day.  You can then decide whether the vampire load is worth worrying about.

Generally, surge suppressing power strips cut power when the main switch is off. But you can confirm that with the Kill-a- Watt.